# Vertical (mis-)aligning of plotmarkers and legend text in V10 PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling, version-10

Consider this example, taken from the docs and modified for a larger font size using `Style` (V10.0):

```
ListPlot[Table[f, {f, {Sin[x], Cos[x]}}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}],
PlotLegends -> (Style[#, 40] & /@ {"sin(x)", "cos(x)"})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The plot markers are clearly aligned at the bottom of the legend text, which does not seem optimal.

Is there a way to influence this aligning?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard a true `\[Pi]` serial edit - my bad for being lazy :D

Comment: I think it's my problem for being obsessive about it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
ListPlot[Table[f, {f, {Sin[x], Cos[x]}}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}],
PlotLegends ->PointLegend[ (Style[#, 40] & /@ {"sin(x)", "cos(x)"}),Alignment->Center]]
```

[image]

**Update:** As noted by rcollyer in the comments `Alignment` is an undocumented option for `PointLegend`. As an alternative, the following old `Pane` trick works without relying on an undocumented option:

```
ListPlot[Table[f, {f, {Sin[x], Cos[x]}}, {x, 0, 2  π, 0.1}],
PlotLegends ->(Style[Pane[#, BaselinePosition -> Center],40]& /@ 
              {"sin(x)", "cos(x)"})]
(* same picture *)
```

**Update 2:** Works with `ListLinePlot` and `LineLegend` combination:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[f, {f, {Sin[x], Cos[x]}}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}], 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[(Style[#, 40] & /@ {"sin(x)", "cos(x)"}), Alignment -> Center]]
```

[image]

Comment: Can we extend that to `ListLinePlot` as well?

Comment: As a side note, `Alignment` is an undocumented option for `PointLegend`.

Comment: Just checked - works nicely with an otherwise identical `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: For my sins, I forgot to accept ...

Comment: One note here: in order to have it so that the labels aren't also centered (as they are in this answer), you need to separate out the horizontal and vertical alignments: `Alignment -> {Automatic, Center}`.

Answer (score 6):

A reasonable workaround is to use `SwatchLegend` with `LegendMarkers` set:

```
ListPlot[
 Table[f, {f, {Sin[x], Cos[x]}}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}],
 PlotLegends -> 
  SwatchLegend[{"sin(x)", "cos(x)"}, LabelStyle -> 40, LegendMarkers -> "Bubble" ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Should the current aligning be considered as buggy in this case? And can we extend the aligning for `ListLinePlot` legends as well?