# Perfect vertical alignment (centering) of PointLegend markers and their labels

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, legending, alignment

I want to produce a stand-alone `PointLegend` for a bunch of plots which I generated. Unfortunately, the markers are slightly off-axis. I have applied all the options discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59925/vertical-mis-aligning-of-plotmarkers-and-legend-text-in-v10-plotlegends/), which did improve things, but not to perfection. Let me demonstrate the issue:

```
layout[pairs_] := 
 Row[Map[Row[{Pane[#[[1]], BaselinePosition -> Center], 
      Pane[#[[2]], BaselinePosition -> Center]}, 
     Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Frame -> True] &, pairs, 1]]

p = PointLegend[
  "DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. 
     Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, ListPlot]), Range[5], 
  LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, Large}, LegendLayout -> layout, 
  LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 20}, 
  Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

The diamond at item 3 is too low and the square at item 2 is too high. Here a screenshot with a horizontal ruler to prove the shift:

[image]

It takes a while to really see what is wrong but one immediately realizes that things are not well aligned. I don't think this can be used in a presentation.

Are there any mode options to force a true centering of the markers?

Comment: I agree, it is a duplicate. I haven't used the right keywords to find that previous question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Direct answer to the question (rewritten after the comments)

It is well known that the default markers are font glyphs and [*Mathematica* can't position font glyphs precisely](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/280). If you need precise positioning, you should use primitive-based `LegendMarkers`. For this purpose I recommend my package [`` PolygonPlotMarkers` ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094/280) :

```
Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]

markers1 = {
   Graphics[{FaceForm[ColorData[97][1]], EdgeForm[], PolygonMarker["Disk", 1]}],
   Graphics[{FaceForm[ColorData[97][2]], EdgeForm[], PolygonMarker["Square", 1]}],
   Graphics[{FaceForm[ColorData[97][3]], EdgeForm[], PolygonMarker["Diamond", 1]}],
   Graphics[{FaceForm[ColorData[97][4]], EdgeForm[], PolygonMarker["UpTriangle", 1]}],
   Graphics[{FaceForm[ColorData[97][5]], EdgeForm[], PolygonMarker["DownTriangle", 1]}]};

PointLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[5], Range[5], LegendMarkerSize -> 30, 
 LegendMarkers -> markers1, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 30}]
```

> [image: legend]

Let us add horizontal line and check how it looks at different font sizes:

```
overlay[legend_] := Module[{w, h}, {w, h} = ImageDimensions@Rasterize[legend, "Image"];
      Graphics[{Inset[legend, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, Automatic], Red, Thick, Opacity[.5], 
        Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, AspectRatio -> h/w, ImageSize -> w]]

t = Table[PointLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[5], Range[5], LegendMarkerSize -> 30, 
    LegendMarkers -> markers1, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> fs}], {fs, {20, 30, 50, 60}}];

overlay /@ t // Column
```

> [image: legends]

Note that in the above all the markers are centered relative to their bounding boxes, while on the plot they are placed [at their centers of mass](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54537/280). Another problem is that they are inscribed into identical boxes (determined by `LegendMarkerSize`) and hence have visibly different areas. Both problems can be solved at once by specifying sufficiently large **symmetric** `PlotRange` (I also show axes which intersect at the center of mass `{0, 0}`):

```
markers2 = Append[#, {PlotRange -> 1, 
      Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Ticks -> False}] & /@ markers1;

PointLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[5], Range[5], LegendMarkerSize -> 50, 
  LegendMarkers -> markers2, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 30}] // overlay
```

> [image: legend]

If one wish to have markers aligned relative to their bounding boxes and at the same time control their sizes, it is achievable by adding `PlotRangePadding` option without explicit `PlotRange` (the larger `PlotRangePadding`, the smaller will be marker):

```
markers1sized = 
  MapThread[Append[#1, PlotRangePadding -> #2] &, {markers1, {.1, .2, 0, 0, 0}}];

PointLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[5], Range[5], LegendMarkerSize -> 30, 
 LegendMarkers -> markers1sized, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 30}]
```

> [image: legend]

`PointLegend` is fairly complicated function which has its own set of undocumented "features" what make it difficult to obtain *exactly* what you wish in every situation. In practice when only a standalone legend is needed it is often easier to construct the legend manually:

```
Grid[{Flatten@Transpose[{Append[#, ImageSize -> 30] & /@ markers1, Range[5]}]}, 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Spacings -> {{{0.8, 0.5}}, Automatic}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 30}]
```

> [image: legend]

```
Table[overlay@
   Grid[{Flatten@Transpose[{Append[#, ImageSize -> 30] & /@ markers2, Range[5]}]}, 
    Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Spacings -> {{{0.8, 0.5}}, Automatic}, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> fs}], {fs, {20, 30, 40}}] // Column
```

> [image: column]

---

### `Offset` size, `ImageSize` and alignment of the markers

When the size of the markers specified in absolute units via `Offset` (please read "Description of the package" section in the [linked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094/280) post) the alignment of the markers may depend on `LegendMarkerSize` option of `PointLegend` (or `ImageSize` option of `Graphics`) when explicit `PlotRange` and/or `ImagePadding` for the marker isn't specified. This comes from how FrontEnd crops the plot when `ImageSize` becomes smaller. Here the red point shows the geometric center of the image, and red rectangle show complete plotting range (`PlotRange` + `PlotRagePadding`), axes intersect at the center of mass:

```
opts = {Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Ticks -> False, Background -> LightBlue,
   (*ImagePadding -> 0, *)
   (*PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},*)
   Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[ImageScaled[{.5, .5}]], 
     EdgeForm[{Red, Thick, Opacity[1]}], FaceForm[], 
     Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}};

Table[Graphics[{FaceForm[ColorData[97][2]], EdgeForm[], 
    PolygonMarker["UpTriangle", Offset[40]]}, opts, ImageSize -> {size, size}, 
   BaselinePosition -> Axis], {size, {75, 60, 55, 50, 40, 30}}] // 
 Row[#, Spacer[5], Alignment -> {Center, Axis}] &
```

> [image: row]

As one can see, when `ImageSize` is large, the center of the image coincides with the center of the plotting range almost exactly. But when `ImageSize` becomes smaller, *relative* plotting range is reduced and some `ImagePadding` is added around it **non-symmetrically**. Hence the center of the image doesn't coincide with the center of the plotting range anymore. We can fix it by disabling `ImagePadding` (uncomment `ImagePadding -> 0` in `opts` above):

> [image: row]

Uncommenting also `PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}` doesn't affects the result because it is the default `PlotRange` when the plot doesn't contain ["tangible"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138081/280) primitives:

> [image: row]

But the straighforward (and correct) approach to align markers with `Offset` sizes at their centers of mass is to specify `BaselinePosition -> Axis`:

```
opts = {};
markers3 := {
   Graphics[{FaceForm[ColorData[97][1]], EdgeForm[], 
             PolygonMarker["Diamond", Offset[20]]}, opts], 
   Graphics[{FaceForm[ColorData[97][2]], EdgeForm[], 
             PolygonMarker["UpTriangle", Offset[20]]}, opts], 
   Graphics[{FaceForm[ColorData[97][3]], EdgeForm[], 
             PolygonMarker["DownTriangle", Offset[20]]}, opts]};

opts = {BaselinePosition -> Axis, Axes -> True, Ticks -> False};
l = PointLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[3], Range[3], LegendMarkerSize -> 35, 
 LegendMarkers -> markers3, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 30}]
```

> [image: legend]

Aligning such markers relative to bounding boxes is more difficult and can be achieved manually by adding `ImageMargins` option (which is defined outside of `ImageSize`):

```
markers4 = MapThread[
   Append[#1, ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, #2}] &, {markers3, {{0, 0}, {0, 7}, {7, 0}}}];
PointLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[3], Range[3], LegendMarkerSize -> 35, 
 LegendMarkers -> markers4, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 30}]
```

> [image: legend]

---

### Internal structure of generated legend

By applying `ToBoxes` to our legend we can see its internal structure on the box level. It is `TemplateBox` with first argument being the list of labels. The option `DisplayFunction` contains a function which will be dynamically applied to the first argument in order to generate a static box structure for on-screen display. We see that this function returns `GridBox` where the pairs consisted of `GraphicsBox` (containing `InsetBox` with our marker) and a placeholder for the corresponding label reside. Each `GraphicsBox` already contains options including `BaselinePosition`, rows are set to be aligned to `Baseline`:

```
Cases[ToBoxes@l, 
 gb_GridBox :> (gb /. 
    g_GraphicsBox :> 
     "GraphicsBox"[Skeleton[…], Options[g, BaselinePosition]]), -1, 1]
```

> ```
> {GridBox[{{
>     "GraphicsBox"[<<…>>, {BaselinePosition -> Scaled[0.157143] -> Baseline}], #1,
>     "GraphicsBox"[<<…>>, {BaselinePosition -> Scaled[0.157143] -> Baseline}], #2, 
>     "GraphicsBox"[<<…>>, {BaselinePosition -> Scaled[0.157143] -> Baseline}], #3}}, 
>   GridBoxAlignment -> {"Columns" -> {Center, Left}, "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}}, 
>   AutoDelete -> False, GridBoxDividers -> {"Columns" -> {{False}}, "Rows" -> {{False}}}, 
>   GridBoxItemSize -> {"Columns" -> {{All}}, "Rows" -> {{All}}}, 
>   GridBoxSpacings -> {"Columns" -> {{0.8, 0.5}}}]}
> ```

We see that `BaselinePosition` of `GraphicsBox` aligns to `Baseline` not its bottom, but the fraction `1/6` (= `0.157143`) of its height (this number isn't constant). Fortunately when `BaselinePosition` is specified in the marker, the setting from the parent `GraphicsBox` is ignored.

These observations suggest a method to cure the legend. Just set up rows to be aligned at the `Center`:

```
alingRowLegend[legend_] := 
 RawBoxes[ToBoxes@legend /. ("Rows" -> {{Baseline}}) -> ("Rows" -> {{Center}})]
```

Comment: Excellent, that is exactly what I need. Sometimes I wonder why all functionality to make publication quality plots has to come from user-defined packages (SciDraw, your package, MaTeX,...)

Comment: It actually seems to me that the markers are normally aligned wrt. their center of mass. I can reproduce your first example only with `Offset[20]`. When I change that value to `10`, it looks like in your last plot. Can you comment on how `Offset` (which I think controls size) and position are related?

Comment: Playing with the parameters, it seems to me that one needs to set `LegendMarkerSize` to the same value as `FontSize` and `Offset` to exactly `2/3` of that value to achieve proper alignment. And even then, the down triangle ends a bit under the 5 in a pdf export.

Comment: @Felix Right, Offset controls size (please read "Description of the package" section in the [linked](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094/280) post). The reason why it also affects alignment comes from the way how FrontEnd by default crops the markers according to the `ImageSize` (`LegendMarkerSize`) option in combination with its default settings for `BaselinePosition`. You can see similar effect with my last example if you set `BaselinePosition -> Center, ImageSize -> {30, 30}` in `align`. May be this last method will be even better for your purposes.

Comment: @Felix We can control how FrontEnd crops the markers by specifying explicit `PlotRange`. For example, with `PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}` and `LegendMarkerSize -> 35` we get markers aligned at their center of mass.

Comment: Thanks, but two more questions: i) How do you define `PlotRange` for a stand-alone `PointLegend` and ii) how would you align the symbols at their bounding box instead of their CM?

Comment: @Felix Please see the **Update** section.

Comment: Excellent answer. It now covers everything that I need. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is a font issue. Look at:

```
Style[Row[{\[FilledCircle],\[FilledSquare],\[FilledDiamond]}], FontFamily->"Arial"]
```

[image]

The centering looks better in Times :

```
Style[Row[{\[FilledCircle],\[FilledSquare],\[FilledDiamond]}], FontFamily->"Times"]
```

[image]

Perhaps the following layout function will serve:

```
layout[pairs_] := Row @ Map[
    Row[{
        Show[#[[1]], BaselinePosition->Center, BaseStyle->{FontFamily->"Times"}],
        Pane[#[[2]], BaselinePosition->Center]
    }, Frame->True]&,
    pairs
]
```

This is what I get:

```
p = PointLegend[
    "DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method/.Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic,ListPlot]),
    Range[5],
    LegendMarkers->{Automatic, Large},
    LegendLayout->layout,
    LegendFunction->"Frame",
    LabelStyle->{FontFamily->"Arial", FontSize->20}
]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1)  I always thought that `FontFamily` doesn't affect such symbols as `\[FilledCircle]` in any way because they are taken from the *Mathematica*'s own font. It is weird that `FontFamily` changes size and positioning. How can it be explained?