# Off center PlotMarker

Tags: plotting, graphics, marker

Let's consider the following simple example

```
s1 = ListPlot[{{1, 1}}, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.03]}];
s2 = ListPlot[{{1, 1}}, PlotMarkers -> {\[EmptyCircle], 30}, PlotStyle -> {Red}];
Show[{s1, s2}, PlotRange -> {{0.95, 1.05}, {0.95, 1.05}}]
```

which gives

[image]

My question is obvious (!): why the plot marker is off center?

Any ideas?

I am using v9.0 in WinXP SP3.

Comment: There are quite a few posts about this, with good solutions as well.

Comment: you can see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/5467)

Comment: or [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84857/how-can-we-make-publication-quality-plotmarkers-without-version-10)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Even though I read the previous posts I still can't make the plot marker to be exactly where I want. Is there any working solution for the particular problem indicated in my simple example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, just avoid using font-based symbols and use `Graphic` items instead:

```
s1 = ListPlot[{{1, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}]}], 0.05}];
s2 = ListPlot[{{1, 1}}, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}]}], 0.1}];
Show[{s1, s2}, PlotRange -> {{0.95, 1.05}, {0.95, 1.05}}]
```

[image]

Any remaining off-centering is due to a finite rastering. In pdf files you won't see it. Also see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137758/38410).