# Right aligned GraphicsColumn of plots with nonstandard aspect ratios exhibits empty space

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, output-formatting, grid-layouts

I have several plots with different y-axis ranges. This is the main reason I want the content being aligned `Right` in a `GraphicsColumn` so that the plot frames are nicely aligned. Example

```
GraphicsColumn[{
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame->True, AspectRatio -> 1/5],
  Plot[100000 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame->True, AspectRatio -> 1/5],
  Plot[100 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame->True, AspectRatio -> 1/5]
}, Right]
```

This results in an awkward image

[image: right aligned graphics column]

The plots seem to be aligned `Right`, just as requested, but the alignment position seems to be running down the middle of the resulting image.

First let's fix the image size by adding `ImageSize->1000`. This results in

[image: larger graphics column]

The unusually large empty spaces on both side of the image remain. I can get rid of them, e.g. by post-processing the resulting pdf files with `pdfcrop` but that somehow defeats the purpose of having all this graphics machinery in the Mathematica language.

Questions:

How to get the last version of the image but with the bounding box tightly wrapped around the content?

Is there another, more elegant way to align several `Plot`-frames in a column or 2D grid?

Answer (score 4):

There is a work around. We can `Frame` all the boxes and making the color of those frames white.

```
GraphicsColumn[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/5], 
  Plot[100000 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/5], 
  Plot[100 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/5]}, 
 Alignment -> Right, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> White]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting that this should fix it.  By the way `FrameStyle -> Opacity[0]` might be a better choice.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I didn't knew that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Manual resizing

[`GraphicsRow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsRow.html), [`GraphicsColumn`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsColumn.html), and [`GraphicsGrid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGrid.html) always give me trouble.  <s>I don't know how to fix this programmatically, but fortunately there is another way.</s>  You can manually rescale the frame by clicking on the graphic so that a gray frame appears:

[image]

Then putting the mouse pointer over the right center control point, holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and dragging:

[image]

### PlotRange

A bit of experimentation shows that it is possible to fix this with [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) and [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html).

```
myGraphicsColumn[gr : {__Graphics}, opts___] :=
  Show[
    GraphicsColumn[gr, opts]
    , PlotRange -> {{Automatic, # + 10}, Automatic}
  ] & @ Max[ First @ Rasterize[#, "RasterSize"] & /@ gr ]
```

Example:

```
myGraphicsColumn[
 {Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/5], 
  Plot[100000 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/5], 
  Plot[100 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/5]}
 , Right
]
```

### Origin of the problem

It is interesting that MMM's `Frame` work-around solves this.  It seems that the frames are drawn directly as `Line` expressions showing that `GraphicsColumn` knows the right size of things.  The problem appears to stem from the automatic `PlotRange` chosen by `Graphics` in the absence of any "tangible" primitives, meaning those beside `Inset`.

The form of the output is something like this:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/5];

Graphics[{Inset[p1, {369, 0}, ImageScaled[{1, 0.5}], {360, 72}]}]
```

[image]

Note all the extra space.  This persists even with zero paddings:

```
Graphics[{Inset[p1, {369, 0}, ImageScaled[{1, 0.5}], {360, 72}]}
 , PlotRangePadding -> 0
 , ImagePadding -> 0
 , ImageMargins -> 0
]
```

[image]

A "tangible" primitive fixes it.

```
Graphics[{
  {LightRed, Rectangle[{30, -40}, {370, 40}]},
  Inset[p1, {369, 0}, ImageScaled[{1, 0.5}], {360, 72}]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for introducing the new term "tangible primitive". An addition: without "tangible" primitives ***and*** with default `PlotRange -> All` FrontEnd always sets `PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}` (it is easy to check by adding `Frame -> True`). Note that when coordinates in the primitive are given in `Scaled` or `Offset` form, this primitive is "intangible".

Answer (score 0):

Based on @LLlAMnYP analysis [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79773/8548), a right aligned version of his `undistortedGraphicsColumn` is then

```
MyGraphicsColumnRight[item_List] := 
  Module[{size = Map[ImageDimensions, item], width}, 
    width = Max[size[[;;, 1]]];
    size = size[[;;, 2]];
    Graphics[
      Table[
        Inset[item[[i]], {0, -Total[size[[;;i]]]}, ImageScaled[{1, 0}]],
        {i, Length[item]}
      ],
      ImageSize->{width, Total[size]},
      ImagePadding->None, 
      PlotRange->{{-width, 0}, {-Total[size], 0}}, 
      AspectRatio->Total[size]/width,
      PlotRangePadding->None
    ]
  ]
```

Using it as in

```
MyGraphicsColumnRight[{
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame->True, ImageSize->500,  AspectRatio->1/5],
  Plot[100000 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame->True, ImageSize->519, AspectRatio->1/5],
  Plot[100 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame->True, ImageSize->503, AspectRatio->1/5]
}]
```

then gives us this right-aligned image:

[image: right-aligned]

Nevertheless, the size of individual plots has to be manually adjusted (see `ImageSize->` above) to get the perfect alignment of all the frames of corresponding plots.

Comment: Your's (and @LLlAMnYP's in the [linked post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79773/280)) usage of `AspectRatio` isn't quite correct since you don't take into account that `ImagePadding` (which is non-zero in your case) is *excluded* from `AspectRatio`. This is the most probable reason why you have to adjust `ImageSize`s manually. Please see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83779/280) dedicated thread for detailed description of how `AspectRatio` actually works.