# Controling the vertical distance between labels

Tags: legending, labeling

Here we have a simple example

```
Clear["Global`*"];

col = {Green, Blue, Red, Purple};
lab = {"Label 1", "Label 2", "Lable 3", "Label 4"};
leg = PointLegend[col, lab, LegendMarkers -> {Style[●, 12]}, LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17}]
```

[image]

Is there a way to reduce the vertical distance between the labels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the (undocumented) option `Spacings`:

```
Row[PointLegend[col, lab, 
    LegendMarkers -> {Style[\[FilledCircle], 12]}, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17}, 
    Spacings -> #] & /@ {.1, .5, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: It's working, even though the option `Spacings` is colored red thus meaning unkown option.

Comment: It would be nice to see the ability to align labels with their markers. it would be more obvious if these were squares. I had to roll my own legend to fix it. Maybe not an appropriate place for this comment, but, nice work as always, kglr!

Comment: @CATrevillian, [Vertical (mis-)aligning of plotmarkers and legend text](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59925/125) may be relevant/useful.